# Set border width for networkx label?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this problem, I just can't find it in any of the networkx documentation and I've been searching for quite a while.

Instead of drawing Nodes for my networkx graph, I draw labels using nx.draw_networkx_labels(). I pass in a dictionary to the bbox parameter of nx.draw_networkx_labels() to set the label color and label border color, but I cannot find what key I should be using to set the width of the label. I would like to signify something in the graph by only coloring the perimeter of a label, but the color differences are not very noticeable with the default width.

Thank you!

Comment: Haven't tested it, but passing a non-zero `edgewidth` to `bbox` should do the trick? Otherwise, have a look at the matplotlib `Text` docs. IIRC, the `bbox` parameters/arguments are just passed through the `networkx` function to there.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thanks for steering me in the right direction. It turned out that the argument I needed was "lw", which takes an integer. I got this information from [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.PathPatch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone ever discovers this and needs to change the border width of a networkx label, the argument to pass into the bbox is `lw`. The ones I used were as follows:

```
bbox = dict(fc="red", ec="black", boxstyle="circle", lw=3)

fc: face color
ec: edge color
boxstyle: the shape of the label
lw: line width
```